# Booting problem after installing updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu after trying it out from a USB disk on my laptop. I made a partition for it, so it shares the HDD with windows 10. Given that at the time I did not have a fast internet connection available, I did not install any updates. Nevertheless the OS worked well: Grub would load, and I could choose to load Ubuntu or skip it. If I skipped it, the boot manager that I installed for windows (suggested by the following site. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-backup-windows-10-safe-way-with.html) would appear instead and I could choose to start windows. 
After I got hold of a decent internet connection I installed the updates, and Ubuntu asked to restart. Upon restart,grub disappeared from the booting process. The notebook jumps just directly to the windows boot manager.
I have looked around at this forum and come up with the boot repair solution. Given that I am currently here, it evidently failed. However, it provides a report tool which can be to some use to you http://paste.ubuntu.com/14883071/
I have also tried holding down shift while booting, again, to no avail.

I would very much appreciate your help on this matter, given that I am a newcomer to this OS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** You've got a non-standard boot system, so your solution will be non-standard as well...  **:/**  So if you want easy recovery once you run into problems, [use our method to install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: can u access  boot device menu, try holding Esc, F2 or F10 depending on ur computer model, if you get there see if u can locate an entry that say something like this "boot from an EFI file"